# SSIS: Is Data stored in the database during the transformation process?

Tags: sql, ssis, relational-database

I'm new to SSIS and would like to ask whether data is being processed in the database during ETL Process or not? Since I have a source with sensitive data and the data shall not be processed or stored in the final database due to compliance reasons.
Everything is on prem. I'm thinking about using SSIS for transformation but it's unclear to me whether data being processed in SSIS is already in the database or not.

I read about a staging process with flat files:

1. Is this a must or can data be transformed without staging and would staging be considered being processed in the database?
2. If yes, is it possible then to use Scripttask and do transformation beforehand?
3. Would transformation in Data flow being considered of the data being in the database for transformation or not?

Comment: SSIS will process in memory if you do not stage it to a table. It is safe to read a flat file into memory, process transformations and only load non-sensitve data to the DB. You can also store sensitive data to the DB using a Symmetric key to encrypt it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/sql-server-and-database-encryption-keys-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So this means if I have a table with sensitive columns from an external source I can delete or group these columns in SSIS data flow? This would not be considered being stored or processed in the database because it's in memory of SSIS and SSIS is also separat from the database?

Comment: Also, I would not recommend using SSIS and a script task if you do not need to. And that is a lot coming from me who almost uses .NET exclusively for data processing. If you find that you need to use script tasks, I would consider a console application to take advantage of asynchronous processing, but that is not always needed. For example, sometimes it is cleaner to use a script task that a complicated derived column.

Comment: Correct, well sort of. SSIS doesn't have memory, your computer/server does. And only the data you send to the DB will ever touch the DB (not all columns of your data flow have to be pushed to the server).

Comment: Since the data is coming from a table, you can use SQL on that table as your source to control the data that you receive.

Comment: What would you recommend using instead of SSIS on Prem? I'm not sure yet what format the source will be. I'm assuming it would be in CSV. In the cloud I would have chosen a serverless python script for transformation but I'm not knowledgeable on prem. The requirement is just the data shall not be processed or stored in the database with the sensitive data, so I have to transform them somehow beforehand.

Comment: SSIS is fine for that. You are in control of what makes it into the DB. If they are so worried about this, why don't they provide you with the transformed data in "whatever" format they want without the sensitive data. That's typically done through an API where Json is the response format. Good Luck